# What is the best way to run code on user create/update/delete/login/logout in Rails 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

What is the correct way to make an HTTP POST request every time the following events occur in a Rails 5.1 application?

- on user creation
- on user update
- on user deletion
- on user login
- on user logout

Comment: Can you specify what to want with description ? because your question not understandable

Comment: Using code. Usually, Ruby. Possibly javascript. Impossible to tell since you gave us no meaningful detail.

Comment: For create/update/delete, you can add callbacks: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: For login/logout, you can add `before/after_action` in your session controller.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted. The question looks clear: I want to make an HTTP POST request to another server whenever users perform those actions. If Active Record Callbacks are the correct way to do that, then write it as an answers and I'll accept the answer. I'm assuming that you mean I should put callbacks into both the User (create, update, delete) and Session (log in, log out) models. I didn't know if there was an established "best practices" way to do this in Rails.

Comment: You got downvote because your question isn't clear. I will give an example...

Comment: I'm not sure how it isn't understandable -- every time a CRUD operation is done on those models, execute some extra code. Jagdeep Singh understood and answered it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment above, I went with [this solution](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html):

> During the normal operation of a Rails application, objects may be created, updated, and destroyed. Active Record provides hooks into this object life cycle so that you can control your application and its data.
>
> Callbacks allow you to trigger logic before or after an alteration of an object's state.